# Hide markers in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rcp, markers

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application and I have custom markers that I display on a diagnostics view. I want the filtering in my diagnostics view to affect the markers as well (if I hide the warnings in my view I want the warnings markers not to be displayed in the editor). Is it possible to hide the markers from the editor without actually deleting them?

Comment: Update supporting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show/hide marker(annotation) can be done in the preference page. You could try programmatically change the warning marker state in the preference store when hiding warnings in the view. Refer to http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html